# Why applying cross validation before training a model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So, I am struggling to understand why is it that, as a common practice, a cross-validation step is done to a model does has not been trained yet. An example of what I am saying can be found in [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/repeated-k-fold-cross-validation-with-python/). A piece of the code is pasted below:

```
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
# create dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=20, n_informative=15, n_redundant=5, random_state=1)
# prepare the cross-validation procedure
cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
# create model
model = LogisticRegression()
# evaluate model
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
# report performance
print('Accuracy: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scores), std(scores)))
```

Questions:

1. What would be the purpose of the cross-validation at that point?
2. Does some training procedure take place on any part of that code?
3. How does RepeatedKFold contributes to tackling an unbalance dataset (let's assume that this is the case).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: purpose of cross-validation before training is to predict behavior of the model. estimating the performance obtained using a method for building a model, rather than for estimating the performance of a model.

Comment: This isn't really a question about programming.  Your questions are better suited on other Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
```

according to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) the "cross_val_score" fits the model using the given cross validation technique, there
in the code above, "model" contains the model that will be fit, and "cv" contains information about the cross validation method that the "cross_val_score" will use to structure the training and CV sets and evaluate the model.

in other words, those are just definitions, the actual training and CV happen inside the "cross_val_score" function.

> How does RepeatedKFold contributes to tackling an unbalance dataset (let's assume that this is the case).

[KFold](https://machinelearningmastery.com/repeated-k-fold-cross-validation-with-python/) CV generally doesn't tackle an unbalanced dataset, it just assures that the result will not be biased by the choice of the training/CV datasets,

> Repeated k-fold cross-validation provides a way to improve the estimated performance of a machine learning model. This involves simply repeating the cross-validation procedure multiple times and reporting the mean result across all folds from all runs. This mean result is expected to be a more accurate estimate of the true unknown underlying mean performance of the model on the dataset, as calculated using the standard error.

if you want to tackle an unbalanced dataset you have to use a better [metric](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) than accuracy, like ‘balanced_accuracy’ or ‘roc_auc’ and making sure both the training and CV datasets have both positive and negative cases.

Comment: Thanks for the response!. So it does fit the model. Right? Does that also mean that, whenever I choose to train the model outside that cross_val_score function, I will be training over an already trained model? Or that model trained inside cross_val_score remains local to that function only?.

Comment: the model fitted is local to the cross_val_score function, however you can use [cross_validate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate) with return_estimator=True to have the trained models returned for new predictions.

Comment: Thanks!. Now, let's assume I already trained a model, and am I happy with it. Can I use the cross_validate function to control its performance? In that case, I want the cross-validate not to train the model, but to use the one I am giving without touching it. Is there any option for doing that?

Comment: i don't think that functionality is available in the API, you can however manually loop over the returned estimators and average their score()